# On click of next button I want to call another lightning component

Tags: lightning, aura

I have created one Lightning Component which contains a "Next" button.

//button code

> lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button--brand"
>   onclick="{!c.gotoURL}">Next /lightning:button>

Once I clicked on this next button I want to be called another component which is for creating new record.

I have written below function in controller.JS

```
//Calling a next component clicking on the "Next" button
gotoURL:function(component,event,helper){
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");      
    evt.setParams({
     componentDef:"NewOpportunityCreation",
    });

evt.fire();
}
```

But when I am clickin on the "Next" button I am getting below error message.

No COMPONENT named markup://NewOpportunityCreation found

STackTrace:
org.auraframework.throwable.quickfix.DefinitionNotFoundException: No COMPONENT named markup://NewOpportunityCreation found

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of this componentDef:"NewOpportunityCreation" use componentDef:"c:NewOpportunityCreation"

Answer (score 2):

You have one syntax error here

```
componentDef:"NewOpportunityCreation",
```

This line will be

```
componentDef:"c:NewOpportunityCreation" //you don't need the comma as well
```

You can navigate only to a component that’s marked access="global" or a component within the current namespace

Comment: Thanks Tushar, Yes I do have access="global" and tried by removing comma but still the same issue.

Comment: @SFDCDev Please will you mention how the other answer solve your problem?

Answer (score -1):

```
({
next : function(cmp, event, helper) {
alert('1');
 var navService = cmp.find("navService");
 var pageReference = {
                     "type": "standard__component",
                     "attributes": {
                                     "componentName": "c__Questionary2"
                                   }, 
                     "state": {
                         'message':'This is the target page'
                     }
                    };
 navService.navigate(pageReference);
}
})
```

Comment: <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>   //put this in your component                 and *quesionary2 is the name of new component that wa want to call on click on the next button